# Keep having to reindex sql tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database on SQL Server 2012 and am having some problems with a few tables that become slow after a while and the thing that helps is rebuilding the indexes. I was wondering if anyone has advice on what could be wrong in any of them, I will post their structure and indexes below. I have not built this structure myself but have full access to modify.

**Table1**

- ID (int, not null)
- Type (tinyint, not null)
- Name  (PK, nvarchar(255), not null)
- fkID (PK, int, not null)
- UID (int, not null)

Indexes:

- I_UID (Unique, Non-Clustered) [UID]
- I_Name (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) [Type,Name]
- pk_Name (Clustered) [Name, fkID]

**Table2**

- ID (PK, bigint, not null)
- Name (nvarchar(50), not null)
- ShortValue (nvarchar(250), null)
- StringValue (nvarchar(max), null)
- IntValue (int, null)
- FloatValue (float, null)
- DateTimeValue (datetime, null)
- BoolValue (bit, null)
- fkPID (FK, int, null)
- fkAID (FK, int, null)
- fkAGID (FK, int, null)
- fkVID (FK, int, null)
- fkCID (FK, int, null)
- fkL (FK, int, not null)
- fkIMID (FK, not null)
- fkPRID (FK, int, null)
- fkNID (int, null)

Indexes:

- I_AG (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) [fkAGID]
- I_IM (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) [fkIMID]
- I_R (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) [fkPRID]
- PK_D (Clustered) 5447370
- I_PDL (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) [fkL]

**Table3**

- ID (PK, int, not null)
- fkPID (FK, int, not null)
- fkAID (FK, int, not null)
- Sort (int, not null)
- Group (nvarchar(50), null)
- Size (int, null)
- FMB (nvarchar(50), null)

Indexes:

- PK_D (Clustered) 5447370
- I_PAA (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) [fkAID]
- I_PAP (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) [fkPID]
- I_PAPID (Non-Unique, Non-Clustered) [fkPID,fkAID]

Comment: Why is name the primary key and not the ID?

Comment: Reverted the previous edit - changed title was misleading and formatting was not much better.

Comment: Good question @BobVale, I don't really think there is a good reason for it so I should probably change that. Also based on the reply below from D Stanley.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great tool that will analyze and, if necessary, rebuild indexes and update statistics is Ola Hallengren's Index and Statistics Maintenance tool/script.  We run this thing nightly, along with the Integrity Check, to keep our databases healthy.

http://ola.hallengren.com/

Comment: This did end up helping quite a bit, however sometimes we have to run it on-demand more than nightly...feels like a bandaid at the moment so I will have to look into it some more.

Answer (score 5):

One column that sticks out to me is this one:

```
pk_Name (Clustered) [Name, fkID]
```

Clustered keys determine the *physical* order of records in the database table.  If `Name` is a string and values are inserted in "random" order (i.e. not always at the end of the table alphabetically) there could be performance problems as the database is always having to "insert" rows into the physical tables.  This could cause the table data to become fragmented, which could reduce performance as well.

Re-building a clustered index also re-organizes the physical data which is likely why you're seeing improved performance afterwards.  Recomputing statistics could also be a factor, but a primary key that results in non-consecutive inserts is usually a red flag.

Also your definition doesn't specify the columns that make up the clustered indices on tables 2 and 3, but based on the name I'm assuming they're indexed by `ID`.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense. I will try it out and see how it goes. Might take a while to determine the effect though.

The primary keys are only on ID for the other two tables.

Comment: Did not notice a big difference doing this, I think the problem is elsewhere so I will keep looking. One question though, does having a column in multiple non-clustered indexes pose a possible performance problem?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar problem.
When you add data to your table the statistics gets updated only if u pass a specific change threshold as described here:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/04/21/sql-server-when-are-statistics-updated-what-triggers-statistics-to-update/

I have not found any good way to overcome this problem except for major changes to the way we work with our DB.
In the meanwhile you can run

```
UPDATE STATISTICS <Table Name>
```

or

```
alter INDEX <Index Name> ON <Table Name> rebuild
```

Every night

Comment: Thanks, I will check that blog post out. Yes we are running a index rebuilding job for these tables, except we have to do it several times a day.